# Статическая сборка Qt5+Qt3D в linux

Tags: qt5, qt, linux

Всем доброе время суток.

Заранее хочу сказать, что собирая динамически (без -static) по этой же схеме всё отлично работает. Но вот статически не получается.

По порядку что и как делаю.

В любой директории созданию следующие директории: depot - для хранения исходников Qt, build_static - для сборки.

```
mkdir -p build_static/qt5
mkdir depot
```

Получение Qt5 из репозитолия:

```
cd depot
git clone git://gitorious.org/qt/qt5.git qt5
```

Получение Qt3D:

```
cd qt5
git clone git://gitorious.org/qt/qt3d.git qt3d
```

Инициализация репозитория Qt5:

```
./init-repository --no-webkit
```

Перехожу в директорию для сборки:

```
cd ../../build_static/qt5
```

Конфигурация (статически -static):

```
../../depot/qt5/configure -developer-build -opensource -nomake examples -nomake tests -confirm-license -static -opengl
```

Компилим:

```
make -j 9
```

Настраиваем для сборки Qt3D:

```
./qtbase/bin/qmake ../../depot/qt5/qt3d/qt3d.pro
```

До этого момента всё отлично, но дальше при компиляции Qt3D:

```
make -j 9
```

сталкиваюсь с ошибкой

```
make[2]: Вход в каталог `/mnt/d/qt5/build_static/qt5/src/quick3d'
make[2]: *** Нет правила для сборки цели `/mnt/d/qt5/build_static/qt5/qtbase/lib/libQt53D.a', требуемой для `../../qtbase/lib/libQt53DQuick.so.5.2.0'.  Останов.
make[2]: Выход из каталога `/mnt/d/qt5/build_static/qt5/src/quick3d'
make[1]: *** [sub-quick3d-make_first-ordered] Ошибка 2
make[1]: Выход из каталога `/mnt/d/qt5/build_static/qt5/src'
make: *** [sub-src-make_first-ordered] Ошибка 2
```

Вопрос: что я делаю не так и как это исправить?

Answer (score 2):

Похоже у них даже баг такой есть: [Static build of Qt fails to compile quick3d (Qt3D)](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-26635).

Comment: у меня другая ошибка. И этот баг поднимался последний раз 24/Jan/13. Мне кажется, что у меня другая причина.

Comment: думаю, они просто ещё не сделали это.

Comment: если так, то это очень плохо..

Comment: @попробуйте уменшить количество ядер при сборке. не 9, а 2 к примеру